# Pandas groupby two columns and only keep records satisfying condition based on count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Trying to filter out a number of actions a user has done if the number of actions reaches a threshold.

Here is the data set: (Only Few records)

```
user_id,session_id,item_id,rating,length,time
123,36,28,3.5,6243.0,2015-03-07 22:44:40
123,36,29,2.5,4884.0,2015-03-07 22:44:14
123,36,30,3.5,6846.0,2015-03-07 22:44:28
123,36,54,6.5,10281.0,2015-03-07 22:43:56
123,36,61,3.5,7639.0,2015-03-07 22:43:44
123,36,62,7.5,18640.0,2015-03-07 22:43:34
123,36,63,8.5,7189.0,2015-03-07 22:44:06
123,36,97,2.5,7627.0,2015-03-07 22:42:53
123,36,98,4.5,9000.0,2015-03-07 22:43:04
123,36,99,7.5,7514.0,2015-03-07 22:43:13
223,63,30,8.0,5412.0,2015-03-22 01:42:10
123,36,30,5.5,8046.0,2015-03-07 22:42:05
223,63,32,8.5,4872.0,2015-03-22 01:42:03
123,36,32,7.5,11914.0,2015-03-07 22:41:54
225,63,35,7.5,6491.0,2015-03-22 01:42:19
123,36,35,5.5,7202.0,2015-03-07 22:42:15
123,36,36,6.5,6806.0,2015-03-07 22:42:43
123,36,37,2.5,6810.0,2015-03-07 22:42:34
225,63,41,5.0,15026.0,2015-03-22 01:42:37
225,63,45,6.5,8532.0,2015-03-07 22:42:25
```

I can `groupby` the data using `user_id` and `session_id` and get a `count` of items a user has rated in a session:

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'session_id']).agg({'item_id':'count'}).rename(columns={'item_id': 'count'})
```

List of items that user has rated in a session can be obtained:

`df.groupby(['user_id','session_id'])['item_id'].apply(list)`

The goal is to get following if a user has rated more than 3 items in session, I want to pick only the first three items (keep only first three per user per session) from the original data frame. Maybe use the time to sort the items?

First tried to obtain which sessions contain more than 3, somewhat struggling to go beyond.

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'session_id'])['item_id'].apply(
            lambda x: (x > 3).count())
```

Example: from original df, user `123` should have first three records belong to session `36`

Comment: So what is the expected output here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to use `groupby` with [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
In [8]: df.groupby([df.user_id, df.session_id]).head(3)
Out[8]:
    user_id  session_id  item_id  rating   length                 time
0       123          36       28     3.5   6243.0  2015-03-07 22:44:40
1       123          36       29     2.5   4884.0  2015-03-07 22:44:14
2       123          36       30     3.5   6846.0  2015-03-07 22:44:28
10      223          63       30     8.0   5412.0  2015-03-22 01:42:10
12      223          63       32     8.5   4872.0  2015-03-22 01:42:03
14      225          63       35     7.5   6491.0  2015-03-22 01:42:19
18      225          63       41     5.0  15026.0  2015-03-22 01:42:37
19      225          63       45     6.5   8532.0  2015-03-07 22:42:25
```

Comment: @chriz what if condition is not three 20? i want to make sure i keep all rated items for users who are less than 20 but users with more than 20 cap it / take first 20 only

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis Oh, in that case change `head(3)` to `head(20)`, and it'll work well.

Comment: @COLDSPEED no need sorting? my original data seems like in order but in case if they are not? this seems awfully simple than I thought I am glad it is... but just thinking...

Comment: Well, if the data is unsorted you would have to sort before using this method.  What do you want to sort by?

Comment: @chrisz just did that as you type, works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `sort_values` followed by `groupby.cumcount`. A method I find useful is to extract any series or MultiIndex data before applying any filtering.

The below example filters for minimum user_id / session_id combination of 3 items and only takes the first 3 in each group.

```
sizes = df.groupby(['user_id', 'session_id']).size()
counter = df.groupby(['user_id', 'session_id']).cumcount() + 1  # counting begins at 0
indices = df.set_index(['user_id', 'session_id']).index

df = df.sort_values('time')
res = df[(indices.map(sizes.get) >= 3) & (counter <=3)]

print(res)

    user_id  session_id  item_id  rating   length                 time
0       123          36       28     3.5   6243.0  2015-03-07 22:44:40
1       123          36       29     2.5   4884.0  2015-03-07 22:44:14
2       123          36       30     3.5   6846.0  2015-03-07 22:44:28
14      225          63       35     7.5   6491.0  2015-03-22 01:42:19
18      225          63       41     5.0  15026.0  2015-03-22 01:42:37
19      225          63       45     6.5   8532.0  2015-03-07 22:42:25
```